# WinAPI - CreateProcessW fails when C:\Program file exists

Tags: c, winapi, createprocess

I run the following C code to create a process. The exe file is located at C:\Program Files\Exes\Start\process1.exe

```
CreateProcessW(NULL, (char*) exePath, 
                           NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
                           flags, 
                           NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
```

Now some computers randomly have this file called Program located at C:\Program which causes create process to fail with the error:

> %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Is there a way to fix this problem apart from renaming the file because there are a few dozen Windows Vms on which this C code is executed. This error randomly happens on a few machines.

Comment: Pass the EXE path as the *first* parameter - the one that specifies the EXE path?

Comment: The second argument to `CreateProcessW` must be a wide string. `(char *)exePath` is wrong, and you should see a compiler error message. If not then adjust your compiler settings.

Comment: @immibis So I pass the exepath as the application name(first parameter) and the command line argument (second parametre) as null?

Comment: You can pass the command line as the second parameter. I'm not sure if it can be NULL, but if the program doesn't care then you could use a blank string, or the program name.

Comment: If it's just the program name, use `CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Program Files\\Exes\\Start\\process1.exe", NULL, ...)` else, declare `wchar_t buf[300];`, fill it, and put `CreateProcessW(NULL, buf, ...)`

Comment: Use `CreateProcessA` if `exePath` is of type `char *`.

Comment: _%1 is not a valid Win32 application_ Another one of Microsoft's world class error messages.

Comment: _Now some computers randomly have this file called Program located at C:\Program_ How did that sneak in there?  Never seen that before.

Comment: @i486 (I used to have one of those) - it isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How does this code even compile? The second parameter to [CreateProcessW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) is defined as a `LPWSTR` which means it should only accept a wide string.

The next problem: as a result of the cast it's not possible to determine what the source of `exePath` is. The reason this is of consequence is that the 2nd parameter is defined as a `LPWSTR`, not a `LPCWSTR` (i.e. a *const* wide string) for a reason: `CreateProcessW` may write to the buffer.

Then the 3rd problem - your exe path had a space in it. When passed as the 2nd parameter (lpCommandLine) `CreateProcess` has some derpy logic to guess where the exe name ends and the command line begins. Which necessitates quote encoding the exe path part of the command line.

When you have the full path to the exe - and no parameters - the simplest / safest thing to do is to just pass it as the lpApplicationName parameter. This IS a const parameter which avoids any potential undefined behaviour that could result if your command line source was a constant string literal etc. And is simply used as the path to the exe to execute, so does not (and can not) have any quoting requirements.

```
    CreateProcess(exePath,NULL,...);
```

---

Aside: Using both parameters to `CreateProcess` essentially lets you set argv[0] of the launched application to be anything you want. So you could run an application from a particular path / exe name, but make argv[0] point at some other path or exe name.

To pass a parameter to the exe, rather than passing the full (quote enclosed) path you could do something simple like this:

```
    WCHAR cmdLine[] = TEXT("console1.exe --version");
    CreateProcessW(exePath,cmdLine,...);
```

---

**Edits** Credit to Paul Sanders and the other comments for pointing out the unquoted exe path, and also caused me to completely break my original answer which had solved that without me realising it.
Credit to RbMm for spotting I had broken my answer, and credit to eryksun for showing me that I've been reading the documentation wrong for almost 20 years now.

Comment: _CreateProcessW may write to the buffer._ Yes, lovely, isn't it?  Apart from all the good stuff in your post, but, as coded, he probably just needs to quote the path.

Comment: @PaulSanders, if `lpApplicationName` is `NULL` then it has to slice out the executable name from `lpCommandLine` to pass it to `SearchPathW`. It does this the cheap/lazy way by temporarily replacing the space after the name with a NUL, rather than copying the substring to a new string.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but it's important to clarify that a Windows process doesn't inherently have `argv`, which is a Unix concept related to the `exec*` family of functions. For compatibility, the Windows CRT's `[w]main` entry point has `argv`, but the real entry point that's called by the loader is passed a pointer to the Process Environment Block (PEB). This includes the `ProcessParameters`, including `ImagePathName` and `CommandLine`, which is redundant of course since an application can call `GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, ...)` and `GetCommandLineW()`.

Comment: @eryksun Yes, I guess it dates back to the days when memory was expensive and programmers were cheap.  But NT was supposed to be _a new start_!  They didn't _have_ to do it this way.

Comment: @eryksun - surely `GetCommandLineW` gets the `CommandLine` from the `PEB`? Certainly the `ImagePath` is redundant. At any rate using argv seems the most compact way of describing the effect of using both parameters.

Comment: for first argument use enclosing `\" ` is error. here must be exactly file name. `WCHAR exePath[] = TEXT("\"C:\\Program Files\\Exes\\App.exe\"");
CreateProcessW(exePath,NULL,...);` this code is fail

Comment: command line is stored in `RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS` structure, pointer to it in `PEB`. but anyway your code is incorrect - *Escape the path to the exe by wrapping it in quotes.* ok only for use in place second argument  - cmdline, but fatal error use it in place first argument

Comment: @ChrisBecke, I meant that the PEB parameter passed to the entry point is redundant, not the PEB itself, which is fundamentally important. `GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, ..)` and `GetCommandLineW` use the PEB, but it's via the thread's TEB, which is accessed using a register, abstracted as `NtCurrentTeb`, i.e. the process parameters are `NtCurrentTeb()->ProcessEnvironmentBlock->ProcessParameters`.

Comment: @RbMm The docs do not make that at all clear. if lpCommandLine is null, then lpApplication is used as the command line. if lpApplication is null, then the first white-space delimited part of the command line becomes the module name. I'm on a Mac so I can't even test.

Comment: @ChrisBecke, `lpApplicationName` is not a command line. It's the executable path, so it should not be quoted, just as you would not quote the file path passed to `CreateFile`, etc

Comment: docs say that in place first argument must be *The name of the module to be executed* - it not parsed. i just test it for sure - got `STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_INVALID` error

Comment: The docs describing quote encoding refers to the "command line", not "lpCommandLine", and earlier the same page says that "lpApplicationName" is used as the command line in the case "lpCommandLine" is NULL. From that description the module name is the first white-space delimited part of the command line (parsed to account for quote's), and the command line can be supplied via lpApplicationName as long as lpCommandLine is NULL.

Comment: It is, admittedly, a clumsily written page with a number of apparent contradictions.

Comment: anyway if we will be use " in *lpApplicationName* `CreateProcess` fail with error `Object Name invalid. `

Comment: @ChrisBecke, if `lpCommandLine` is `NULL`, then `lpApplicationName` is quoted as the command line. If `lpApplicationName` is `NULL`, then the image path is determined by parsing `lpCommandLine` and calling `SearchPathW` to find the executable in the base API's custom search path.

Comment: *Its argued via the comments that the command line cannot contain spaces when passed via the 1st parameter.* - unclear. first argument not parsed. and this is not command line at all. here can be any count of space(if file path containing it). but here must be exactly file path - full or partial. can not be any " symbols. can not be any arguments. only exactly file name

Comment: Your edit changes this to be technically correct, but if you have the full path it should be passed as `lpApplicationName` (no quotes), and let `CreateProcessW` copy it to a quoted string for the command line. This avoids a pointless call to `SearchPathW`.

Comment: Oh good grief. My derp. The way I read the page was that, if lpCommandLine was NULL then lpApplicationName would be treated as the command line - i.e. to be parsed as a command line. The implication that it would simply become its own parameter completely flew over my head.

Comment: I'm re-evaluating the last 20 years of my life right now. Working on an edit now that I finally know whats going on.

Comment: @ChisBecke Is it hot where you are today too? :)

Answer (score 3):

Chris makes a lot of good points there and you should take them on board, but the real issue, as immibis says, is that you are using the `CreateProcess` API incorrectly.  The way you've done it requires `exepath` to be quoted, if it contains any whitespace.

So, instead, after you've fixed all the issues that Chris has raised, do this:

```
CreateProcessW (exePath, NULL,
                NULL, NULL, TRUE, 
                creation_flags, 
                NULL, NULL, &startupInfo, &processInformation);
```

i.e. just swap the first and second parameters around (and perhaps use a more descriptive name for `flags`, as I've done here).

You can pass any command line arguments you might need in that second parameter, if that ever becomes a requirement.  And please, [read the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw).

---

**Edit** (to get my rep back :)

Also, as Chris says, `exepath` needs to be a wide string here, so I took out your (redundant) cast which would in fact generate a compiler error (C++) or warning (C) (so, a warning,  guess, since your post is tagged As C, thank you @Barmak).

Anyway, if you now don't get one, then `exepath` must in reality already *be* a wide string so all is well.  If not, then you obviously need to fix that, but I imagine this whole issue is just a typo in your post since you clearly *did* have your code working in order to report the behaviour you are observing.

Comment: This depends on what `exePath` is still, if it's a narrow string then this is bad

Comment: @MM Sure, but I _said_ that already by referring to Chris's answer.

Comment: Answers should standalone. If there are important points, they need to be made in the text of the answer. If the answer you refer to is removed or edited then what?

Comment: @David Why would he do that?  No, I'm not going to put that in.  I removed the cast, that's enough.  If the OP gets a compiler warning, then _he should act on it_.  My guess: `exepath` is already a wide string, and the cast (which will be having no effect) is just an oversight.  Otherwise, the code would not function at all (and clearly, from what the OP tells us, it kinda does).

Comment: @David Sigh.  Edited my post (I thought it was a good one), I hope you approve.

Comment: @David And that I get my rep back, since I have done as you asked.  After all, perhaps / maybe / probably, you're right.

Comment: The cast has to go, but the code in the question does not compiler. It's not a warning to pass the wrong type there, it's an error.

Comment: @David Oh yes, you're right, sorry.  Been posting too long this morning.  I'll tweak my post again, thanks. ... OK, done that, silly me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question is tagged C, the C compiler will only issue a warning for the incorrect cast.

Comment: Thank you @Barmak, I must have my dunce's cap on this morning, I have (yet again) updated my post.  Looks like I'm not going to get any change out of David though.  Serves me right, I suppose, for saying to him _that's pathetic_ (even if I thought that downvoting me just for this, in fact, was).  After all, if he _really_ cares about this issue, he can edit my post himself.

Comment: @Barmak Thanks, good advice.  It just ticked me off, that's all, I don't think he and I get on.

Comment: @barmak hmm, I did not know that. Is that really the case in modern C standards? Seems like a recipe for mistakes.

Comment: @David Well, that's C for you - bare metal.  TU for vote. Not sure there is any such thing as 'modern' C.

Comment: @PaulSanders There is such a thing as modern C. The standard has been updated. The current standard is C11.

Comment: @David Ah me.  OK, modern-ish.  The changes are hardly revolutionary - they don't dare.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't know C very well. According to [C11 draft](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html) version *"6.3.2.3 ... A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type."* In VS 2017 C `float f; MessageBoxW(0, &f, 0, 0) or MessageBoxW(0, (int*)L"text", 0, 0) ` will generate a warning only. Also `int *ptr = malloc(size)` will compile in C without warning, where `void*` is a special case.